# How should we use git branches cleanly and effectively?

Tags: git, github

We have a branch `staging` which is our master branch. This is the branch that gets deployed.

We have two developers. We want to work on features in isolation, but ensure compatibility before we push changes to `staging`.

How are we supposed to do this?

Here's what I thought we could do.

- I branch off from `staging` to create `feature-avatar-edit`.
- My coworker branches off from the same commit of `staging` to create `fix-profile-alignment`. He commits some stuff and finishes this branch, and merges it back into `staging`. He deletes `fix-profile-alignment`.
- I want to continue working on `feature-avatar-edit`, but I want my coworker's changes to exist in `feature-avatar-edit`, else I may create issues later when I finish and merge into `staging`. (Basically, when I'm almost done working on `feature-avatar-edit`, I want to confirm that it works perfectly, including with the changes from `fix-profile-alignment` that have been added to `staging`.)
- I switch to `staging` and do `git pull` to get the recent changes my coworker committed. **I then do a `git rebase`** to basically "move" the point at which `feature-avatar-edit` diverged from `staging`.
- I review the current state of `feature-avatar-edit`, make any fixes necessitated by my coworker's commits showing up in my branch, and merge into `staging`. I delete `feature-avatar-edit`.

What I've found so far is that rebase tends to introduce duplicate commits. What I *expect* to happen is this. Before rebase:

```
A    staging
| \
B |  merge fix-profile-alignment into staging
  C  feature-avatar-edit
```

After rebase:

```
A    staging
|
B    merge fix-profile-alignment into staging
  \  
  |
  C  feature-avatar-edit
```

1. How can I achieve the above without creating duplicate commits in our history? Or would working like this be okay?
2. How does the use of pull requests enter into it? Is it okay to do `git rebase` after a pull request has been created, assuming only one person works on that branch at a time?

Comment: What "duplicate" commits? That shouldn't really ever happen I don't think. Have you seen [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) it is a fairly popular development model.

Comment: http://imgur.com/YrEcuHH There are commits there with the same name and the same contents, but different hashes.

Comment: Are you serious? If you use the same commit message it will be "duplicate". I wouldn't care how GitHub's representation of the repository is working, please show us the problem in your working tree(s) .e.g. using gitk or something similar.

Comment: "Are you serious?" Don't insult me. I'm asking a question because I don't know all the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your "duplicate" commits might be there because you have pushed to a remote (if not, we need you to show an example of history with duplicate commits).

Starting from:

```
--A---B---C - staging
       \---D - feature - remote/feature
```

After `git checkout feature && git rebase staging`:

```
           /---D' - feature
--A---B---C - staging
       \---D - remote/feature
```

You get a new commit `D'`, but `D` is still there.

If that is your case, and if you can get away with destroying `D` altogether on your remote (no one else is using it or would get mad at you), you can update the branch on your remote with `git checkout feature && git push <remote> feature -f`.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer - the step I was lacking was `git push -f`. Without doing a force push, the rebased commits are treated as new commits *on top of* my commits that have already been pushed to remote, creating 'duplicates'.

Comment: Not really *on top of*, rather *in addition to*. If you've rebased, `D'` is not a child of `D`. If you meant `on top of` as in the new commits are children of the ones you had already pushed, that is.

Comment: "On top of" was an unfortunate word choice - "in addition to" is definitely more accurate. :) "`D'` is not a child of `D`" is what I was getting at.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the way it is supposed to be done if you want a linear history.

There are duplicate commits because the *content* of the files from the rebased commits is different (since it contains changes from `fix-profile-alignment`), hence the `SHA` hash is different.

You can delete them from your history by [deleting the commit object](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Commit-Objects)

As for the rebase, you are still on `feature-avatar-edit` after it, and `stagging` has not been modified. If you merge into stagging, then you should immediatly `push stagging` to the remote to avoid latter conflicts (otherwise you would have to do `git pull --rebase` to keep the history linear). But you can also do regular rebase to be sure your feature integrates correctly with the others (for example if the other developpers is developping a lot of small features and pushes regularly to `stagging`).

Comment: Or rather because the "duplicate" commits do not have the same *parents*, or line of parents. The `SHA` is different because of this, but you are right that in effect, the content of the files differs.